# I got a negative number while trying to return a long long value

Tags: c++, function-definition, integer-arithmetic

I created a function `seriesSum` to return a sum of the series of a number, and I used `long long` return data type but it returns a negative number if I insert for example `46341` output will be `-1073716337` and what I am expected is `1073767311` here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long long seriesSum(int n)
{return n*(n+1)/2;}

int main()
{
    cout<<seriesSum(46341); // expected 1073767311 but output is -1073716337

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change parameter to `unsigned long long int n`.

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this.

Comment: The reason is also explained in any [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which are also available as PDFs for free.

Comment: `46341*46342` overflows, and in this case is `-2147432674` (but is **undefined behavior**).  `-2147432674/2` is `-1073716337`.  Mystery solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument variable `n` is an `int`.

All operations you perform in the function are done using `int` values. Which you will *overflow*, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Change the argument type to `unsigned long long`.

I also recommend you change the return type to be `unsigned` as well, if you're not going to get negative results.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code is that you are using objects of the type `int` in this expression statement

```
return n*(n+1)/2;
```

instead of objects of the type `long long int`.

You could write for example

```
long long seriesSum(int n)
{
    return n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2ll * ( n + 1ll ) : ( n + 1ll ) / 2ll * n;
}
```

Though as the sum is calculated for non-negative numbers then it is better to declare the function like

```
unsigned long long seriesSum( unsigned int n )
{
    return n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2llu * ( n + 1llu ) : ( n + 1llu ) / 2llu * n;
}
```